# Error when pass parameter to stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I have a simple search code

my stored proc :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sptest]
(
    @model NVARCHAR (20)
)
AS
begin
    SELECT * from table where model = @model
end
```

my code in c# :

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comm.Connection = con;
comm.CommandText = "sptest" ;
comm.Parameters.Add("@model", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;
```

if I delete this line :
`comm.Parameters.Add("@model", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;`

 my code runs without error!!

but when i add this line , visual studio shows an error :

> Procedure sptest has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

where is my mistake ?

Comment: First, change your `SqlDbType.Int` to `SqlDbType.NVarChar`. Second, I don't see _any_ sp called `allmovie` in your code.

Comment: Your stored-proc expects an `nvarchar(20)` parameter, and you supply an `int`-typed parameter, that you give a `string` value. What is the *real* type of that "model" column in that table?

Comment: thanks its my mistake . but my procedure saved without this line:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stored procedure expects an `NVARCHAR(20)` parameter and you pass an `INT`. This is the problem. So, I suggest you change the type of the parameter you pass to `SqlDbType.NVarChar`.

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@model", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = textBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
 SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.Connection = con;
            comm.CommandText = "sptest" ;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@model", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text; 
...
```

After edit:

```
 SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.Connection = con;
            comm.CommandText = "sptest" ;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@model", SqlDbType.NVarChar,20).Value = textBox1.Text; 
...
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer Following Code

```
CREATE PROC SPTest
(
@model      NVARCHAR (20)
)
AS

    BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON

        SELECT * FROM <<TABLE_NAME>> WHERE model = @model


    END
```

C# Code

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("<<ConnectionStringValue>>");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    com.CommandText = "SPTest";
    com.Parameters.Add("@model", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = "<Parameter Value>";

    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

    Rest Of Code Goes Here
    ...
    ...
    ...
```